# How to make SonarQube's unit test coverage widget see the data?

Tags: java, widget, unit-testing, no-data

I am new to SonarQube and I was trying to setup a simple quality monitoring for evaluation cases. I want to setup the unit test coverage widget but it tells me "no data". I know for sure there are plenty of unit tests.

Same goes for integration test coverage widget.